# CreateProcess error = 2, the system cannot find the file specified error

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I have Android Studio 2.3.3 on Windows and also Git for Windows. I cloned a repository from GitHub ( VCS->Checkout from version control->Git->pasted the link ) and tried to run it. But the gradle sync failed giving this error

```
CreateProcess error=2, the system cannot find the file specified
```

I checked the log and I noticed this

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "H:\GitClone\apps-android-commons\app"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

The path given is the location I chose during checkout.
I tried changing the path for git.exe from ...\bin\git.exe to ...\cmd\git.exe in Android Studio.
I also added the path for git.exe to my environment PATH variables but the error has persisted.
Other answers on SO mostly tell to do these steps but as I had already done these I had to ask a new question.
Also, my friend advised me to install Github Desktop but I cannot because I have a 32 bit OS.
Note- I am completely new to version control.
Edit - A part of the log

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'git''
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:220)
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:204)
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:340)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.run(BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.java:39)
... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'git'
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
... 4 more
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but what would Git have to do with a Gradle build within Android Studio?  Git is primarily about versioning your source files, rather than having something to do with the build process.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The exact question I had in my mind but I did those steps simply because the word git was mentioned in the log

Comment: Do your Gradle scripts make any mention of Git?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No! Infact there are only 2 occurance of the word git in the entire project and both are in the gitutils.gradle file

Comment: What does this file do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is only 20 lines of code and it is giving 'git rev-parse --short HEAD' and 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD to the command line . I don't know what they mean though as I am completely new to git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure how you add `git.exe` to your PATH: while in Android studio yo need to specify the full path including `git.exe`, you would need to add only the parent folder of `git.exe` in your `PATH`:

```
set PATH=C:\path\to\Git\bin;%PATH%
```

C:\path\to\Git can be any folder where you uncompressed the sef-extracted archive [`PortableGit-2.15.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.15.1-64-bit.7z.exe).

That needs to be [done in your USER Environment variables](https://serverfault.com/a/33704/783), and you need to close and re-open Android Studio if you want any process (like Gradle) launch from it to inherit your new `%PATH%` value.

Comment: Solved my problem but I still have one question:why do we need set the path in android studio as well as in the PATH variable

Comment: @BarneyChambers In the CMD session from which you are launching Android Studio. Or, for persistence, in your user environment variables: https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/create-custom-environment-variables-in-windows/. But then open a new CMD session, in order to inherit the new PATH.

Comment: After setup git path in environment, need to restart the computer. In most of case eclipse do not work with updated path till you restart the system. I did and working for me. Thanks!