# Not able to run the perl script in java

Tags: java

```
package checkpl;

public class runpl {

public static void main(String args[]) {
         
        Process process;
         
        try
        {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:\\result\\ptrrefresh.pl");
            process.waitFor();
            if(process.exitValue() == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Command Successful");
                    System.out.println(process);
                }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Command Failure");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.toString());
        }
        }
}
```

I have the perl script file in `C:/result folder`. I have written the above program to run the Perl script in Java but it is giving the exception below:

**`Exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "perl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`**

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try giving it the full path of the `perl` executable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CreateProcess error = 2, the system cannot find the file specified error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043878/createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error)

Comment: And use `ProcessBuilder`. It gives you simpler control of stdout and stderr, which you should be processing, but aren't